# Query MS Access Database from Form button with Visual Basic for Applications

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

Within my Microsoft Access Database I have a form object. This form object has just 1 button on it. I want this button to open a `mailto` link with all of the email addresses in my Customers table as the to field. I have the opening of the `mailto` with test data to make sure this works via `Application.FollowHyperlink("mailto:a@a.com,b@b.com,c@c.com")` which works fine.

I need to be able to be able to either query a database table/query from the VBA. Also if possible I'd preferably want it without an absolute path to the `.accdb` file as this file may be moved which would break this button completely.

I've tried `Application.OpenCurrentDatabase("database.accdb")` but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You want this code to reside inside the same database that contains the table??? If so, there is no need to worry about database location as you would just reference 'CurrentDB'.  As for the query, just 'select * from customers;' then spin through the recordset building the 'To' string.  If you still need help, please post the code you are using now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open the default access db, you do not need to open the db again, you can just use the CurrentDB object.

And if you want to open other access db, my suggestion is save the absolute path to the current db table, and query this table to get the absolute path.